# Prevent application fom being killed without using a Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, launcher

My application is a Launcher. I want it to not being killed when the user leave the home screen (because when it get killed I have to reload all app icons and it takes a long time) but i don't want to use a Service. AOSP Launchers 1, 2, and 3 do it and they don't use any Service to do it.

What I tried is to copy the AndroidManifest.xml of these Launchers :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".Launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Launcher" >
```

But it doesn't change anything for me.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that : ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle))

> The Android system attempts to keep application process around for as long as possible, but **eventually will need to remove old processes when memory runs low**

Comment: OK, but how do all AOSP based launchers never redraw ?

Comment: they probably redraw faster than yours... Maybe look at your icon loading code.

Comment: Maybe they redraw faster than mine but i am sure that they redraw less often because when they redraw it takes a few seconds to show

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can save all data in database. As for images you can save them on sdcard.

When user restarts your app - only after that you load all information. In this case any information will not be lost and the app will start very fast.